# print(tabulate(...)) to pretty print multiIndex pandas ?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, python-3.5, pweave

Say i have a pandas data frame:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate

A = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,(3,6)), index= ['uno', 'dos', 'tres'])
A.columns = ['A','B','C','D','E','F']
A.index.names = ['type']
A.columns.names= ['group']

h = [A.index.names[0] +'/'+ A.columns.names[0]] + list(A.columns)
print(tabulate(A, headers= h, tablefmt= 'grid'))
```

which gives:

```
+--------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| type/group   |   A |   B |   C |   D |   E |   F |
+==============+=====+=====+=====+=====+=====+=====+
| uno          |   3 |   1 |   6 |   0 |   7 |   0 |
+--------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| dos          |   9 |   5 |   3 |   0 |   6 |   6 |
+--------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
| tres         |   6 |   7 |   4 |   6 |   8 |   4 |
+--------------+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+-----+
```

Now adding a layer:

```
iterable = [['A', 'B'], ['AA', 'BB', 'CC']]
A.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterable,
                                       names= ['group', 'subgroup'])
A.index.names = ['type']
```

will give using a print statement:

```
group     A        B      
subgroup AA BB CC AA BB CC
type                      
uno       3  1  6  0  7  0
dos       9  5  3  0  6  6
tres      6  7  4  6  8  4
```

Typically, this does not present well on a document such as pweave.

How can i use print(tabulate(...)) such as i have each group and sub group to shown on separate line ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With [tabulate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tabulate) version 0.8.1 or newer,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate

A = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,10,(3,6)), index= ['uno', 'dos', 'tres'])
A.columns = ['A','B','C','D','E','F']
A.index.names = ['type']
A.columns.names= ['group']

iterable = [['A', 'B'], ['AA', 'BB', 'CC']]
A.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(iterable, names= ['group', 'subgroup'])

h = [A.index.names[0] +'/'+ A.columns.names[0]] + list(map('\n'.join, A.columns.tolist()))
print(tabulate(A, headers= h, tablefmt= 'grid'))
```

yields

```
+--------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| type/group   |    A |    A |    A |    B |    B |    B |
|              |   AA |   BB |   CC |   AA |   BB |   CC |
+==============+======+======+======+======+======+======+
| uno          |    8 |    4 |    3 |    3 |    4 |    2 |
+--------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| dos          |    1 |    1 |    1 |    9 |    8 |    9 |
+--------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| tres         |    0 |    4 |    3 |    6 |    1 |    7 |
+--------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```